Issue with constraints_equality in botorch optimize_acqf_mixed
I am having trouble using equality_constraints. I am trying to use optimize_acqf_mixed for multifidelity bayesian optimization, and i need to use constraints_equality. If I the tensors dtype in the constraints is float, I have an error saying that it should be long,bytes, int or bool , but if I put the tensors in another type, I have RunTimeError (dot : expected both vectors to have same dtype, but found Long and Float). If then I change the bounds dtype,the optimization function is not working anymore "RuntimeError: linalg.svd: Expected a floating point or complex tensor as input. Got Long" . So ... I am stuck and wondering if enabling equality constraints is even possible... If anyone has any advice I would be very interested,
I tried all dtypes but got an error each time. Here is a snippet of my code
def optimize_mf_and_get_observation(acq_func):
    candidates, _ = optimize_acqf_mixed(
        acq_function=acq_func,
        bounds=bounds.to(dtype=torch.long),
        equality_constraints=[(torch.tensor(list(range(7)),dtype=torch.long), torch.tensor([1.0] * 7,dtype=torch.long), 1.0)],
        fixed_features_list=[{11: 0.5}, {11: 1.0}],
        q=BATCH_SIZE,
        num_restarts=NUM_RESTARTS,
        raw_samples=RAW_SAMPLES,
        options={"batch_limit": 5, "maxiter": 200},
    )
    

